# Hive sql query not returning any result + equivalent in Sparklyr

Tags: dplyr, hiveql, sparklyr

Data looks like:

```
ARTICLE_ID, ORDER_ID, ARTICLE_TIME
2567, 1112, 2019-01-16 20:40:00.0
2670, 1117, 2019-01-16 21:40:00.0
2569, 1112, 2019-01-16 20:45:00.0
```

Suppose we have many orders, each order containes several articles.
Each article is bought at a specific time article_time,

My problem is the get all articles having article_time between -/+ 300s from the time of purchase of a specific article_id to be the first greater or equal than a given value.

Suppose the value we are looking for is 66.5.

1-  we have to get the first value(article_id) greater than 66.5 (here it is 67) 
2-  we take the timestamp of the found value (67) t, and we filter by it so we get all articles bought within -/+ 300s within this timestamp t

This is the query I tried, but it returned nothing.

```sql
SELECT order_id, article_time as `time`, article_id as `article`
FROM  
   db.orders `a`
JOIN 
   (select order_id as `idd`, min(article_id)  as `minn` FROM db.orders   
   WHERE article_id>=66.5   
   AND category=1  
   GROUP BY order_id) `b`  
ON (order_id=idd AND a.article_time between b.minn-300 AND  b.minn+300)
```

I also try to create it using sparklyr, but I dont know how to make the similar join in dyplr:

```
orders<- orders_tbl%>%
group_by(orders$order_id)%>%
arrange(orders$time)%>%
filter(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can directly filter instead of performing a join.

Hive query -

```
select order_id, article_id,article_time from db.orders
where article_time >= (from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(select article_time from db.orders where article_id = 66.5)-300)) 
and article_time < (from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(select article_time from db.orders where article_id = 66.5)+300));
```